# After pressing back i am unable to see my required status on the input field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have a component with two pages. i have required fields and i can see it initially. But when i press next button i can still see the required fields. But when i am navigating back by pressing back button can see the fields but not with required status. I dont know why?? can anyone tell me where the problem is?

this is my component code

```
 <aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="showOne" type="boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="showTwo" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="step" type="Integer" default="1"/>
<div class="slds-modal__header">
    <h1>This is step {!v.step} of 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.showOne}">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning:input name="input1" label="input1" required="true"/>
        <lightning:input name="input1" label="input1" required="true"/>
        <lightning:input name="input1" label="input1" required="true"/>
        <lightning:input name="input1" label="input1" required="true"/>
    </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning:input name="input1" label="input1"/>
        <lightning:input name="input1" label="input1"/>
        <lightning:input name="input1" label="input1"/>
        <lightning:input name="input1" label="input1"/>
        </div>
    </aura:renderIf>
</div>
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.showTwo}">
       <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning:input name="input2" label="input2"/>
        <lightning:input name="input2" label="input2"/>
        <lightning:input name="input2" label="input2"/>
        <lightning:input name="input2" label="input2"/>
    </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning:input name="input2" label="input2" required="true"/>
        <lightning:input name="input2" label="input2" required="true"/>
        <lightning:input name="input2" label="input2" required="true"/>
        <lightning:input name="input2" label="input2" required="true"/>
        </div>
    </aura:renderIf>
</div>

<div class="slds-modal__footer">
    <lightning:button name="Prev" label="Back" onclick="{!c.handlePrev}"/>
    <lightning:button name="Next" label="Next" onclick="{!c.handleNext}"/>


</div>
```

this is my controller code

```
    ({
    handleNext : function(component, event, helper) {
        var showOne = component.get("v.showOne");
        var showTwo = component.get("v.showTwo");
        var step = component.get("v.step");
        step++;
        if(showOne==true) {
            component.set("v.showOne",false);
            component.set("v.showTwo",true);
            component.set("v.step",step);
        }
    },
    handlePrev : function(component, event, helper) {
        var showOne = component.get("v.showOne");
        var showTwo = component.get("v.showTwo");
        var step = component.get("v.step");
        step--;
        if(showTwo==true) {
            component.set("v.showOne",true);
            component.set("v.showTwo",false);
            component.set("v.step",step);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but `aura:renderIf` is a deprecated component.  I would try `aura:if` and see if you still get the same issues.  I've had inconsistent behavior with `aura:renderIf` on some of my projects in the past

Comment: @BrianMiller yes you are right. Aura:renderIf is bit buggy. using aura:if makes the code work

Comment: thanks @BrianMiller .. using aura:if the code worked perfectly fine,

Comment: Amazing! I'll move my comment into the answer section

Answer (score 1):

`aura:renderIf` is a deprecated component, so `aura:if` should fix your issues. I've had inconsistent behavior with `aura:renderIf` on some of my projects in the past.